# ¿Por qué ajax antepone un espacio vacio en data return?

Tags: jquery

Tengo una paetición AJAX desde jquery hacia PHP y estaba teniendo un problema con la información que me retorna PHP, sin embrago depurando, encontré que no es PHP quien me regresa espacios vacíos si no que ajax lo antepone en el data return del success.

¿Alguien sabe porqué? y lo más importante ¿como corregirlo? 
Honestamente ya he realizado peticiones anteriores y este inconveniente nunca me había ocurrido, sin embargo no logro identificar mi error.

Gracias.

```
/*Eliminar Entrevista*/
    $('.eliminarve').click(function(){
        var token = $(this).attr('id');
        swal({
            content: true,
            title: '¿Realmente deseas hacer esto?',
            text: 'Toma en cuenta que se perderá la información y no es posible recuperarla.',
            icon: 'warning',
            buttons: {
              cancel: {
                text: "Cancelar",
                value: null,
                visible: true,
                className: "btn btn-danger",
                closeModal: true,
              },
              confirm: {
                text: "Confirmar",
                value: true,
                visible: true,
                className: "btn btn-primary",
                closeModal: true
              }
            }
        }).then(function(value){    
                if(value==true){
                    var datos = new FormData();
                    datos.append('eliminarVEntrevista',true);
                    datos.append('tokenVE',token);
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"../../views/ajax.php",
                        method:"POST",
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        cache: false,
                        data:datos,
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            $("#loading").removeClass('d-none');
                        },
                        success: function(){
                            alert(retorno); 
                            $("#loading").addClass('d-none');

                            console.log(retorno);
                        },
                    });
                }
            });
    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta el momento hice esto, pero no creo que sea la mejor solución:

```
alert($.trim(retorno));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Seguro que todo está bajo control en tu PHP? Revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11593384/5587982). Y prueba a quitar el tag de cierre de PHP `?>` y toda línea o espacio sobrante antes o después de enviar el dato.

Comment: Valida siempre que no alla espacios luego del cierre o antes de la apertura de php ya que estos espacios son tomados en cuenta `<?php ?>`